# URL Rewrite problem. (Many directory)

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I'd like to make a htaccess file, which can make a good structure for my websites.

My .htaccess is now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|pl|txt)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```

(based on Sombat's comment, and about 30 try :P)

And I want to make this, with it:

for every elements but `(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|pl|txt)`

if domain.xx/admin redirect to the domain.xx/admin directory and don't make a rewrite at all
i mean: let me use domain.xx/admin/index.php?asd=1&asdd=2

else rewrite everything as rule one, to index.php.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add another `RewriteCond` directive after the one you have now that will exclude the admin directory.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/.*
```

That will prevent your `RewriteRule` from being applied if the `RewriteCond` matches your admin path.  The order of RewriteCond and RewriteRule  directives is important, so be sure to put it before the RewriteRule that you want it to affect.

Comment: You cool. Thanks. Btw your name is almost saturday in hungarian. It's szombat. :)

Comment: Hmm... I tested that rule and it worked on my setup.  Try `.*` instead of just `*`, that was a typo on my part, but the rule should still technically work.

Comment: Finally: just the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin/` was good for me :/ Thanks for your help. High5 from Hungary :P